# Конвертация звукового файла с помощью NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, аудио, wav, naudio

При конвертации wav файла по алгоритму A-Law звук на выходе получаеться плохого качества.

```
WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(in.wav);
var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), stream), new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\out.alaw", c);
```

---

Если делаю это так:

```
 WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(in.wav);
 var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
 var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);
 WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\out.alaw", c);
```

то звук играет в 2 раза медленнее.

---

Подскажите как правильно использовать эту библиотеку или посоветуйте другую библиотеку.

Comment: А частота дискретизации не маловата ли?

Comment: @Bulson мой PBX только 8000 ест.

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko, при ограничение в 8000 кадров/секунду сложно получить аудио хорошего качества. NAudio выдает Вам почти максимальное качество для таких требований.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan кодга я конвертирую через sound forge то получаю более качественный звук при том же формате. Думаю проблема в том что я сначала конвертирую в PCM 16kHz а потом с него в A-law так как напрямую конвертация не поддерживаеться, но пока не знаю как по другому.

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko, ну так sound forge и не бесплатная :) В таком случае Вы можете попробовать `Alvas.Audio`.

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko, хотя говорят его уже не поддерживают разработчики.